# Can I install Ubuntu on an HP R007TX?

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Can I install Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion R007TX notebook?

And for that, from where I can get the drivers from HP that I'll need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) ... Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (or Ubuntu 14.10, but 14.04 is a Long Term Support release)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Please also have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special drivers in Ubuntu like in Windows. Most features are supported by default without any external drivers.

If any extra proprietary drivers are needed the system will detect it itself and ask you to install.

There are a few sites that show Ubuntu compatibilty, for example:http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?page=2&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&level=Any&query=hp+pavilion